# Saving values in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I have a couple `QLineEdit` widgets in my project. I enter something, call methods and close the window. Can I save values in `QLineEdit` widgets, so when I open an app, values which I entered were there? I only can set values by default using `QLineEdit::setText`, but I need more flexible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I save values in `QLineEdit` widgets, so when I open an app, values which I entered were there?

Not particularly. Widgets don't implement this, you have to code that yourself. You can use a regular file for each `QLineEdit` to store the contents, or you can use [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) class. Simply, you'll want to read the settings when the application starts and write when it exits.